# Visual Studio Web Performance Test - Using Multiple Rows From One Data Source in One Test

Tags: visual-studio, datasource, performance-testing, load-testing

I am a bit new to Performance, Load, and Stress testing, and so I apologize if I do not explain myself well.

I have created a performance test that attempts to log in three times. The first two times it fails, but the third it should work. I attached two Data Source files to the test. One contains invalid login credentials and the other contains valid login credentials.

Would I have to attach the invalid login credential data source twice, and have the first failed log in attempt use one, and the second use the other? That way the first and second failed login attempts do not use the same row from the data source? Is there a way to have the test choose another row from the data source?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Why does one test make three attempts Rather than making a complicated test with complicated data sources, let the test framework do the work for you? For a load test I would have one test that logs in and expects failure. Another test logs in and expects success. Then run the first test at 66% (or 67%, you choose) and the other at 34% (or 33%) to get the two expected fails for each expected success.

Comment: That is probably my best bet and the easiest way. I don't know why I was trying to do it all in one test. I was probably making things too complicated. Thanks!